# Performance Counter read access very slow - How does Task Manager do it?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, performancecounter, taskmanager

Im trying to implement a performance monitoring tool, I want to monitor basic things such as Memory and CPU.

I am attempting to do so by using Performance Counters as I believe this is what Task Manager is using behind the scenes too. I have no idea how Task Manager is able to do this however as to me it seems to take a VERY long time to retrieve process data using this method:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var pcs = Process.GetProcesses()
                    .Select(p => new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", p.ProcessName));

                var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                foreach (var pc in pcs)
                    pc.NextValue();

                Console.WriteLine($"Time taken to read {pcs.Count()} performance counters: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Has anyone got any suggestions on how to do this or how even Task Manager or Process Explorer is able to do this?

Comment: Did you try running without debugging? Debug may affect the performance of LINQ statements significantly. (just guessing)

Comment: Task Manager and Process Explorer are written in a lower level language (C++ most likely)

Comment: Task Manager does not create a new `PerformanceCounter` instance inside of the update loop. Move it out and add a `.ToList()` on the end and I bet you will see a lot lower times.

Comment: @PaulStelian - Yes, running it in release mode makes no difference, try running the code yourself. The code is not running slow, its the Performance Counter read that is slow.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Moving the GetProcess outside the loop has no effect. Note that the StopWatch timing is not around that part of the code anyways. Try running the code yourself to see.

Comment: Task Manager used `ZwQuerySystemInformation` for this task

Comment: Some of these values you can obtain directly from [`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) instance but e.g. CPU data is in "bad" format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does Task Manager do it?

he used calls to `ZwQuerySystemInformation`, `ZwQueryInformationProcess`, `ZwQueryInformationThread` ..
Task Manager maintain database of active processes and periodically update this info by calling  `ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation,)` - so got array of `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` on exit.
add new entries if found new process, yet not in `DB`, remove entries for died processes, update info for lived
`SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` already containing a lot information of process. additional information can be get by open process and call `ZwQueryInformationProcess` with appropriate info class

if you want implement a performance monitoring tool, without "quantum effect" (when the measurement affects the state itself) you need use this ntdll api. for definitions look at http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntexapi_8h_source.html
despite this is undocumented, existing functions and structures not changed how minimum from win2000 (so ~17 years) - new version of windows add a lot new info classes, some fields which was spare/unused in old version - can become used, but old(legacy) not changed

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129903/discussion-on-answer-by-rbmm-performance-counter-read-access-very-slow-how-doe).

Comment: Im going to accept this one as the correct and answer as even tho I didn't get a satisfactory answer to how I am to do this in a performant way it did answer my question as to how Task Manager is able to do it.

Comment: @mikeysee - i can suggest you begin from call `ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation,*)` - on return you got array of `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` - one per process (begin from virtual Idle process) with a lot of information about every process already (name, thread count, memory usage, create time, i/o count etc) - so not call any managed functions but only this and look for performance. in any case it is a good learning test. i can show code for this but only on `c++`